# Determining if a string is an Isogram

Tags: python

**I have two solutions to the task and they are all passing the visible tests but when it is time to submit, I keep getting my failed to pass all tests. There are still some hidden tests my code isn't passing.**

The task reads as follow:

Write a program that checks if a word supplied as the argument is an Isogram. An Isogram is a word in which no letter occurs more than once.

Create a method called `is_isogram` that takes one argument, a word to test if it's an isogram. This method should return a tuple of the word and a boolean indicating whether it is an isogram.

If the argument supplied is an empty string, return the argument and False: `(argument, False)`. If the argument supplied is not a string, raise a `TypeError` with the message 'Argument should be a string'.

Example:

```
is_isogram("abolishment")
```

Expected result:

```
("abolishment", True)
```

The visible tests:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class IsogramTestCases(TestCase):
  def test_checks_for_isograms(self):
    word = 'abolishment'
    self.assertEqual(
      is_isogram(word),
      (word, True),
      msg="Isogram word, '{}' not detected correctly".format(word)
    )

  def test_returns_false_for_nonisograms(self):
    word = 'alphabet'
    self.assertEqual(
      is_isogram(word),
      (word, False),
      msg="Non isogram word, '{}' falsely detected".format(word)
    )

  def test_it_only_accepts_strings(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as context:
      is_isogram(2)
      self.assertEqual(
        'Argument should be a string',
        context.exception.message,
        'String inputs allowed only'
      )
```

I wrote two different solutions to the task and they both passed the tests without errors but when I try submitting I got
 "Test Spec Failed
Your solution failed to pass all the tests".

Please any elegant way of solving this task?

Solution 1:

```
def is_isogram(word):
    if type(word) != str:
        raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')

    elif word == "":
      return (word, False)
    else:
        word = word.lower()
        for char in word:
            if word.count(char) > 1:
                return (word, False)
            else:
                return (word, True)
```

Solution 2:

```
def is_isogram(string):
    if isinstance(string, str) and len(string) != 0:
        string = string.lower()
        if len(string) == len(set(string)):
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
    elif not string:
      result = False
    else:
        raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')

    return string, result
```

Comment: Do you fail some testcase or do you run out of time? The former is usually off-topic here.

Comment: @Graipher it passed all the testcases I listed above.  It just refuses to submit, indicating there are some hidden tests i dont know about. I guess

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, as you've indicated that it doesn't work as intended - It doesn't pass the hidden tests. [You are also holding us to this requirement](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/153739/#comment290891_153743).

Comment: This question is off topic since you don't want people to review your code, but you want us to guess what is a hidden test and fix your code.

Answer (score 3):

I would write it as a mix of your two solutions. Checking if the set of the string has the same length as the string is probably the best way to check for an isogram.

On the other hand, the control structures in your first code are nicer, because there is less nesting and it does the same thing.

You should make sure you use a consistent number of spaces for indentation. You seem to be using 2, 4 and 6. PEP8, Python's official style-guide, recommends 4.

```
def is_isogram(word):
    if not isinstance(word, str):
        raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')
    if not word:
        isogram = False
    else:
        isogram = len(word) == len(set(word.lower()))
    return word, isogram
```

Does the specification say anything about if `A` and `a` should count as the same letter?

Answer (score 2):

The **Solution 2** is a way to go, yet you can write it more succintly:

```
def is_isogram(string):
    if isinstance(string, str) and len(string) != 0:
        string = string.lower()
        return string, len(string) == len(set(string))
    if not string:
        return string, False;
    raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: still refuses to pass some mysterious hidden tests but passed the visible ones..

Comment: @NifemiSola-Ojo Can you give the link to the assignment?

Comment: This returns `(0,False)` for the input `0:int` instead of raising a `TypeError`

Comment: @ovs My answer was editted by the OP.

Comment: @coderodde But this is not a behavior the OP changed in his edit (he only made it conform with the requested interface), it is due to you asking for `if not string` first, which matches `0`, since it is falsey. Likewise `is_isogram([])` would also return `([], False)`, instead of `raise TypeError(...)`.